# Setting usesCleartextTraffic in Eclipse Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to set the Android attribute

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in an Eclipse Android project, but when I do so, it gives me the error:

No resource identifier found for attribute 'usesCleartextTraffic' in package 'android'

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem. I needed to target a more recent SDK. Unfortunately doing so create a whole host of other problems which I will have to sort through, but they are unrelated to this question.